# What is the goal of somebody probing my aws ec2 instance with apache2?

Tags: bots, probing

From `access.log` I found weird visiting pattern. What would be the purpose of this kind of probing?

```
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:14 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/1phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 195 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:14 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/2phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:14 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/3phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:15 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/4phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:15 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/MyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:15 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/PMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:15 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/PMA2011/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:16 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/PMA2012/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:16 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/PMA2013/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:16 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/PMA2014/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:17 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/PMA2015/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:17 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:17 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/admin/db/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:17 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/admin/pMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:18 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/admin/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:18 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/admin/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:18 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/admin/sqladmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:19 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/admin/sysadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:19 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/admin/web/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:19 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/administrator/PMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:19 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/administrator/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:20 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/administrator/db/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:20 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/administrator/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:20 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/administrator/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:20 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/administrator/pma/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:21 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/administrator/web/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:21 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/database/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:21 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:22 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/db-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:22 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/dbadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:22 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/dbweb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:22 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:23 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/phpMyAdmin-3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:23 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:23 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/phpMyAdmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:24 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:24 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/phpmyadmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:24 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/webadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:24 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/webdb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:25 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/db/websql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:25 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/dbadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:25 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:26 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/myadminphp/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:26 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysql-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:26 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:26 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysql/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:27 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysql/db/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:27 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysql/dbadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:27 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysql/mysqlmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:27 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysql/pMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:28 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysql/pma/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:28 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysql/sqlmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:28 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysql/web/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:29 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysqladmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:29 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/mysqlmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:29 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/php-my-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:29 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/php-myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:30 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpMyAdmin-2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:30 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpMyAdmin-3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:30 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpMyAdmin-4/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:31 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:31 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpMyAdmin2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:31 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpMyAdmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:31 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpMyAdmin4/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:32 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpMyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:32 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:32 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpmy-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:32 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpmy/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:33 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpmyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:33 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:33 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpmyadmin1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:34 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpmyadmin2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:34 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpmyadmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:34 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phpmyadmin4/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:34 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/phppma/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:35 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/pma/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:35 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/pma2011/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:35 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/pma2012/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:36 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/pma2013/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:36 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/pma2014/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:36 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/pma2015/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:36 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/program/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:37 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/shopdb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:37 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:37 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/php-myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:38 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:38 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/phpMyAdmin2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:38 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/phpMyAdmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:38 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/phpMyAdmin4/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:39 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/phpmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:39 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/phpmy-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:39 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/phpmyadmin2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:39 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/phpmyadmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:40 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/phpmyadmin4/ HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:40 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/sql-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:40 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/sql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:41 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/sqladmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:41 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/sqlweb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:41 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/webadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:41 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/webdb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
219.106.219.16 - - [11/Mar/2016:15:00:42 +0200] "HEAD my.aws.ec2.instance:80/sql/websql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 158 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
```

Comment: As @ceejayoz said, bots are scanning all ips for vulnerable software. You can avoid this with modSecurity and fail2ban

Comment: Thanks, will take a look on your recommendations

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Any web server on the public internet will see this sort of traffic.

Automated bots crawl all possible IP addresses looking for vulnerable versions of common software (including but hardly limited to phpMyAdmin, WordPress, Drupal, [IIS exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimda), etc.).

Answer (score 5):

If you use apache2 just include following line into your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.*)Jorgee$
  RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

So the bot will receive a 403 error and the request is not forwarded to your php application (which probably would open a database connection to respond with a 404 error)